# Autocomplete in django grappelli - no "add" button

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I have a ForeignKey field in admin which is rendered using django-grappelli like that:

[image]

However when I use grappelli autocomplete lookups the field is rendered without "add" button:

[image]

How can I have both: grappelli's autocomplete and "+" button? There is nothing in the [docs](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#autocomplete-lookups)...

Comment: maybe you should create ticket for your request in grappelli

Answer (score 0):

Seems like old question but anyway.. You can add object with Django Grappelli autocomplete lookup. When you click magnifier icon, you should see Add button within list interface. Make sure you have appropriate permissions to add this type of object.